# pswmm & swmmio conduit diameter modify

Tags: pyswmm

My purpose is optimization for conduit cost.
constraint is zero node flooding and zero node surcharges.
However, the diameter of the conduit in the network is not modified. Below is the code I wrote.

from pyswmm import Simulation, Nodes, Links, SystemStats
import pandas as pd
import pyswmm
import swmmio

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------

inp_path = 'R:/networks/workshop_rainfall_ty.inp'

cost = {0.3 : 20000,
0.45 : 35000,
0.6 : 50000,
1.00 : 85000,
1.20 : 100000,
1.50 : 150000}
with Simulation(inp_path) as sim:

```
system_routing = SystemStats(sim)
model = swmmio.Model(inp_path)
properties = model.links.dataframe[['Length', 'Geom1']]
conduit_id = list(properties.index)

for conduit in conduit_id:
    properties['Geom1'][conduit] = 1.5

cost_conduit = []
for conduit in conduit_id:
    cost_network = properties['Length'][conduit] * cost[properties['Geom1'][conduit]]
    cost_conduit.append(cost_network)

print(f'Network Conduit Cost is : {sum(cost_conduit)} KRW')

for step in sim:
    print(system_routing.routing_stats['flooding'])
```